# Didn't find class "package.Generated_for_debugger_class..."

Tags: java, android, sorting, kotlin

I'm trying to use:

```
cards.sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) { it.rarity })
```

and it's throwing a:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
file "/data/app/com.example.well.clashroyaleguide-s3TV3daRKxWLNuuDx9eeoA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/
com.example.well.clashroyaleguide-s3TV3daRKxWLNuuDx9eeoA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/
com.example.well.clashroyaleguide-s3TV3daRKxWLNuuDx9eeoA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/
com.example.well.clashroyaleguide-s3TV3daRKxWLNuuDx9eeoA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/
com.example.well.clashroyaleguide-s3TV3daRKxWLNuuDx9eeoA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/
com.example.well.clashroyaleguide-s3TV3daRKxWLNuuDx9eeoA==/split_lib_slice_...9_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/
,nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.well.clashroyaleguide-s3TV3daRKxWLNuuDx9eeoA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

It's happening with any method of sorting and comparing.
I try to search similar problems, but nothing really help.

Comment: maybe need try to check correct package name on top of you kotlin class

Comment: The package was wrong, thanks :)